# Enable bluetooth keyboard for Pinephone running PostmarketOS

Tags: alpine-linux, smartphone

I am using a Pinephone with PostmarketOS and can't get my bluetooth keyboard "TrackPoint Keyboard II" to function.

It's getting connected over `bluetoothctl` but is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enable uhid kernel mod with `sudo modprobe uhid` and if you wish to autoload it add a file like /etc/modules-load.d/bluetooth-keyboard.conf containing `uhid`